# Is p-value correction necessary/required for this problem?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, count-data

Suppose I have multiple regions of a tissue that consists of multiple subtypes of a tumor. I want to compare the significance of differences between these various tumor subtypes (i.e How they differ w.r.t the regions). My contingency table should look like this:

[image]

I was wondering if in this scenario p-value correction is valid or not and how would I appropriately correct for p-values here.

Comment: Could you tell us how many p-values you have and what hypotheses they are for?

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing a single chi-square test (which seems like what you are doing) then there are no multiple comparisons to correct for.

If you actually are doing several tests, then, as Jacob Cohen said, long ago "this is a subject on which reasonable people can differ."  Remember that, when you correct for multiple comparisons, you lose power.  Also remember that it's an interesting question what "multiple" means.  Is that all the tests in one paper? Or all the tests anyone has done on this topic? Or all the tests you will ever do in your life? Or what?

I'm not a fan of correcting these, in general, partly because I am not really a fan of p values. But it partly depends on the field and your research. In general, in my work and that of my clients, there was very strong reason to suspect that the null was false. Call this a prior if you like, go full Bayesian if you like, but I just use it to further my antipathy to p values.

OTOH, if you are really doing purely exploratory work, where you genuinely don't have much idea whether the null is true, then p values are useful (this is what Fisher was often doing, trying out all sorts of fertilizer on crop yields).

Answer (score 4):

##### The Need for Corrections

**There is no reason to utilize a p value correction with respect to standalone chi-square tests.** The reason being is that a normal chi-square test only spits out one p value based on the entire contingency table. In other words, you are only conducting one hypothesis test on the entire table, and thus the probability of errors in estimation are constrained to a single testing of the hypothesis. Therefore there is no need to adjust for pairwise comparison error rate (PCER).

**The situation would be different if for some reason you were conducting multiple chi-square tests on additional contingency tables.** Typically you find p value corrections are more common for things like ANOVA-based pairwise comparisons, where uncorrected tests of several group comparisons may lead to problematic Type I error rates. This is because here you are actually conducting multiple hypothesis tests instead (though this to a degree may also not be ideal, as you may end up reducing power of these tests in the process). For a detailed discussion on this topic, refer to the citation I provide at the end of my answer.

As a side note: make sure to report descriptive data and nominal magnitudes of association (such as the phi coefficient), as testing the null hypothesis alone isn't all that useful in my opinion.

##### Reference

Midway, S., Robertson, M., Flinn, S., & Kaller, M. (2020). Comparing multiple comparisons: Practical guidance for choosing the best multiple comparisons test. PeerJ, 8, e10387. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.10387